# Not Able to click in Radio Button - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

Tried to select from Radio Button, Check on Console the Element is there and **its not under Iframe**:

```
$x("//*[@id='featuresCollapse1']/div[1]/label/span")
    (2) [span.overlay, span.overlay]
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-6 my-1 feature-input-wrapper   text-left">
<input name="radio0" data-index="1" id="Personal Accident for Driver only" hidden="" type="radio"><label data-code="PA-DO" data-value="60" class="radio-inline custom-component featureInput p-0 radio-no form-group">
<span class="overlay" tabindex="0"></span> 
<label data-value="60" class="feature-name">Personal Accident for Driver only<span class="option-price font-weight-bold ml-2"> 60 </span> </label></label></div>
```

the Xpath of the radio is :  `private final By PAforDriverOnly = By.xpath("//*[@id='featuresCollapse1']/div[1]/label/span");`

Tried here to check if it Display or not .. but its not " Reading the Exception message

```
try {
    driver.findElement(PAforDriverOnly).isDisplayed();
    System.out.println("driver.findElement(PersonalAccindent).isDisplayed();");
    String Persional = driver.findElement(PAforDriverOnly).getText();
    System.out.println(Persional);
    driver.findElement(PAforDriverOnly).click();
    System.out.println("driver.findElement(PersonalAccindent).click();");
    //getTextAct(ProceedToCheckoutBtn);
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("The Exception Message of Verify Button : "+e);
}
```

and here tried to use JavaScriptExcutor, but Failed on WebDriverWait,
once to remove it, its reading the JavaExcutor but not Give any Action  :

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(PAforDriverOnly);
new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(PAforDriverOnly));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", myElement );
System.out.println("JavaScriptExcutor -  Click on RadioButton");

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Btnclick(PAforDriverOnly);
```

Comment: First `System.out.println("driver.findElement(PersonalAccindent).isDisplayed();");` will print exactly the text 'driver.findElement(PersonalAccindent).isDisplayed();' not result of `driver.findElement(PersonalAccindent).isDisplayed();` as `Boolean`. Second what exception do you get? Can you provide url?

Comment: @pburgr : check out his past records, he will answer himself.

Comment: @pburgr yah i did that to check if its can be display it or not.. this is fine but my question for why not able to select the Radio button .. tried on two way options

Comment: @cruisepandey mean of?

Answer (score 0):

I hope your xpath is wrong,
because your xpath is pointing to label. try to point it to **input** tag.

use this **//input[@id='Personal Accident for Driver only']** or use it on your way to find the element but you need to drill down to input tag.

Comment: Tried that one from before its Failed  `Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //input[@id='Personal Accident for Driver only'] ` ... once select the Element on Radio Button display the Xpath of Element is `//*[@id="featuresCollapse1"]/div[1]/label/span` @Jayanth Bala